# If a point forms a point image in curved mirror then how do images of objects in curved mirror get magnified?

Tags: geometric-optics

If we assume a object lying between the pole and focus of a concave mirror , then a virtual,enlarged and erect image is formed. 
Now by ray diagram the top of the object form a virtual point and so does the bottom. Then how does the image gets enlarged if there is ono-one corresspondence between the points of object and its image?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically a point is a position in space and as such has no size/dimension so you are quite right in thinking about how you could produce a magnified version of a point.

In the context of image formation with a mirror you have to think of a small region of space which does have a size.  You can make that region of space as small as you like and for convenience call that small region, a point.

So consider an object made up of pixels (small regions of 2D space, voxels in 3D space) and the magnified image being made up of all those pixels having been magnified.
The smaller the object pixels, potentially the better is the magnified image a good reproduction of the object.
In the context of image formation using visible light then it is not much use imagining that the object pixels as having a dimension smaller than that of the wavelength of visible light as diffraction effects will prevent improved reproduction of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put it: points don't get magnified, but the distances between points can be magnified or reduced.